# Aws s3 access using vpc-endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, endpoint, vpc

Suppose I create a vpc and a vpc-endpoint in region1.

Can I communicate to an s3-bucket-in-region2 using this vpc-endpoint, i.e. without using the internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, VPC endpoints to not support cross region requests. Your bucket(s) need to be in the same region as the VPC.

[Endpoints for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html)

> Endpoints currently do not support cross-region requests—ensure that
>   you create your endpoint in the same region as your bucket. You can
>   find the location of your bucket by using the Amazon S3 console, or by
>   using the get-bucket-location command. Use a region-specific Amazon S3
>   endpoint to access your bucket; for example,
>   mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com. For more information about
>   region-specific endpoints for Amazon S3, see Amazon Simple Storage
>   Service (S3) in Amazon Web Services General Reference.